# Kafka Conenct: Automatically terminating after processing all data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to backup and restore a huge amount of data in a Kafka topic to various destinations (file, another topic, S3, ...) using Kafka Connect. However, it runs in a streaming mode and hence never terminates. But in my scenario it should exit automatically after processing all data that is currently in the topic (it is ensured in my context that all producers are shut down before the backup starts).

Is there any option/ parameter so that a Kafka Connect connector automatically terminates after all current data is processed and e.g. stored in a file?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such option. You can create "watchdog" checking lag on your Kafka Connect group.id and once lag is processed, e.g. = 0, you shutdown the process.

As we do it in our company: we start consumer to process messages every 3-6 hours to process lag, create file and then terminates. File is being uploaded to other destination.

Comment: Thanks, that what I also want to do, however, what happens if lag never reaches zero (e.g. many fast producers and backup to S3 via slow upload). So, we are now trying to build a watchdog observing the offsets.

Comment: There is already script for that `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --group <group name>`, from this point it's super easy to implement simple bash/python script. Parse values and take actions based on the offsets.

Comment: Even though you shut down the process, though, couldn't `flush.size` amount of records still be sitting in memory of Connect consumer, and not written to the destination?